# What is difference between JSX literal and a component? React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: reactjs

Error: Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: . Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?
at App

```
const withHigherOrderComponent = (Component) => {
 console.log(Component);
return <Component />;
};

const BaseTodoList = ({ data = [] }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((item) => (
      <div key={Math.random()}>{item}</div>
     ))}
</ul>
 );
};

const TodoList = withHigherOrderComponent(BaseTodoList);

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: Depends what you mean by “literal” here. E.g., a raw string (not wrapped in {‘some string’}) is a string literal in JSX. IIRC there’s a lint rule to ping string literals.

Comment: Check the code that I have  in desc.

Answer (score 3):

your HOC does not return a component (*which should be a `function` or `Class`*), but it calls the passed component and returns the result.

It should be

```
const withHigherOrderComponent = (Component) => {
  console.log(Component);
  return () => <Component />;
};
```

Comment: So, my problem that I returned a result of a component but I should return a component, right? When I passed Component parameter then I just return a result of func but not the func itself

Answer (score 1):

You can also do as fallows :

```
const withHigherOrderComponent = (Component) => () => {
    console.log(Component);
    return <Component />;
};
```

Syntax will depend, if class or function is used and readability on return content and HOC parameters.